# Create duplicate rows in Power BI table using Power Query using date columns

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, powerquery

I have a Power BI table sourced from blob storage. It has below structure
Here, I am constructing a composite column called "CustomKey" so that I can establish a relationship with another table.

| MID | SIP | ValidFrom | ValidTo | CustomKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c2 | 08/01/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 1_c2_08_2022 |
| 2 | c3 | 12/24/2022 | 12/31/2022 | 2_c3_12_2022 |

Since the source has validFrom & ValidTo that can span across multiple months, I would like to have my table to like this so that mappings are possible from other table which has this customKey for 09/10/11 months of 2022.

| MID | SIP | ValidFrom | ValidTo | CustomKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c2 | 08/01/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 1_c2_08_2022 |
| 1 | c2 | 08/01/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 1_c2_09_2022 |
| 1 | c2 | 08/01/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 1_c2_10_2022 |
| 1 | c2 | 08/01/2022 | 11/30/2022 | 1_c2_11_2022 |
| 2 | c3 | 12/24/2022 | 12/31/2022 | 2_c3_12_2022 |

Can anyone guide me on how to accomplish this in Power Query?

I did try List.Generate() by passing in the ValidFrom & ValidTo & then tried to expand the list but it fails stating "Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Date."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"MID", Int64.Type}, {"SIP", type text}, {"ValidFrom", type date}, {"ValidTo", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Generate(() => Date.Year([ValidFrom])*12 + Date.Month([ValidFrom]), let End_Month = Date.Year([ValidTo])*12 + Date.Month([ValidTo]) in each _ <= End_Month, each _ + 1)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Month", each if Number.Mod([Custom],12) = 0 then 12 else Number.Mod([Custom],12)),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Year", each if Number.Mod([Custom],12) = 0 then Number.IntegerDivide([Custom],12) - 1 else Number.IntegerDivide([Custom],12)),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "CustomKey", each Number.ToText([MID])&"_"&[SIP]&"_"&Number.ToText([Month])&"_"&Number.ToText([Year]))
in
    #"Added Custom3"
```

The Power Query formulas will help you get the correct output/result.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @kevin. The missing piece is when the ValidFrom & ValidTo span across years like 12/01/2022 ValidTo being 05/15/2023. Can you help with that please

Comment: @AnandaPrasadBandaru. I updated the answer for the above case.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks for putting in the effort to help out. I did manage to get it to work using: List.Generate(    () => [ValidFrom], let ValidToVar = [ValidTo]
in each _ <= ValidToVar, each Date.AddMonths( _ , 1)). Then using additional calculations like you did (in a different way though)

Comment: You're welcome! That's a great idea. Good experience for me. Thanks!